# Download image with Javascript and convert it to a Blob

Tags: javascript, html

With HTML5 and FileReader/Blob I can convert from/to Blobs/dataURIs, but I'm wondering if I can download an image from a remote URL and convert it to a Blob (or a dataURI).

If this is possible, how would I do it?

Comment: `xhr.responseType="blob";`

Comment: @dandavis Not very helpful, but it gave me a clue where to look at.

Comment: if you would have posted code, i could have fixed it for you. i could have been more specific i guess, but i'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it myself:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', attr.ngfDefaultSrc, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
   if (this.status !== 200) return;
   var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: this.response.type});
   //rest of the code that uses the blob goes here
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: `this.response` is already a blob, and the mime should be set already by the Content-Type header, so you probably don't need the extra step of concating the blob into a new blob. `var blob=this.response;`